# Xsl does'nt load the image from xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml:

```
<TEI>    
<text>
    <body>
      <div>
        <pb facs="01.jpg"/>
        <panel facs="#p1" characters="#Matt_Feazell">
          <caption facs="#p1c1">My old pal <hi rend="italic">Matt Feazell</hi> called the other
            day.</caption>
          <balloon facs="#p1b1" who="#Matt_Feazell">So, Scott, what's your next project going to be now that you've
            finished <q>Zot</q>?</balloon>
        </panel>
      </div>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

and this xsl

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >



    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <img alt="sorry" src="{/TEI/text/body/div/pb/@facs}"  ></img>

    <xsl:value-of select="/TEI/text/body/div/panel/balloon"/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried various solutions, like  and different source, filelocation, linking method, but could not figure out a reliable solution. Please, any help would be great, this problem stuck in my head. Thank you very much for the help and the lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating HTML so using `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` is probably wrong, use `method="html"`. Other than that, your stylesheet does create an `img` result element with the `src` attribute being set to `01.jpg`, thus, if the browser does not render the image, then it is probably in a different location. XSLT does not render anything anyway, it transforms (XML) input to XML or HTML or plain text output.

Comment: I will find you and I will hug you, sir. Its an overlook but sooo huge, i cant even say.